# ¿Cómo puedo escribir varias veces un mismo select con datos consultados de SQL server?

Tags: php, sql, select

Lo primero de todo, llevo un par de semanas aprendiendo html,css y php por lo que desconozco muchas funciones que seguro me serían utiles.

Quiero realizar una tabla editable donde para cada celda el usuario pueda elegir diferentes opciones que dependen de una consulta a una base de datos. Cada celda debe ser única y debe almacenar el dato que se le asigne y posteriormente mostrarlo.

He podido crear fácilmente la estructura de la tabla con todas las filas que contiene mi base de datos.

```html
<tbody>
      <?php 
      $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [FIFO] ORDER BY Orden");
      while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
      
      <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row['Orden']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba1']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba2']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba3']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba4']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba5']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba6']?></td>
       </tr>
```

Se ve algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que queria es que en modo edición (que lo tengo que implementar) en cada celda apareciera un select con las opciones de receta que van en funcion de otra consulta a mi base de datos. El problema que tengo es que las opciones de los select son iguales en todas pero cada select debe ser único para poder asignar un "name" e identificar cuál se ha editado. Y aquí ya no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. Estoy haciendo algo así:

```html
<tbody>
      <?php 
      $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [FIFO] ORDER BY Orden");>
      while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){
        $results2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME!='FIFO' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME");  
       ?> 
       <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Orden']?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba1">
                    <option value="-">-</option>
            <?php   while ($row2 =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results2)){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['TABLE_NAME']; ?>"> <?php echo $row1['TABLE_NAME'];?></option> <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba2">
                    <option value="-">-</option>
            <?php   while ($row2 =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results2)){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['TABLE_NAME']; ?>"> <?php echo $row1['TABLE_NAME'];?></option> <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            
        etc...
```

Sin embargo esto solo funciona para la primera columna. Luego ya no aparece ninguna opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He pensado en hacer una petición individual para cada "select" pero se vuelve insostenible hacer tantas peticiones a la base de datos. No se si hay una manera de hacer un solo select y "copiarlo" para cada celda. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Deberías sólo realizar una llamada a la API que obtiene las opciones para el select, se la asignas a cada row de la tabla, y cuando quieras identificar que celda se modificó utilizar el id de la celda, no las opciones que entrega el select :)

Comment: ¿pero cómo asigno las opciones del select a cada row de la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

utilizaste un while dentro de otro while hizo que se repitiera una y otra vez colocando los mismos datos en todos los options, de hecho ese es el problema que tienes.

intenta  asi:

```
<tbody>
      <?php 
      $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [FIFO] ORDER BY Orden");
      while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){ ?>
      
      <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row['Orden']?></td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba1">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba1'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba1']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba2">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba2'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba2']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba3">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba3'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba3']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba4">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba4'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba4']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba5">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba5'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba5']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <select name="<?php echo $row['Orden']?>_cuba6">
<option value="<?php echo$row['Cuba6'] ?>"><?php echo$row['Cuba6']?></option>
               <select>
                </td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: conozco la syntaxis pero no conozco los metodos que utilizas para las consultas, yo uso mysqli($conexion, Consulta); de esta forma, parece que intentas colocar el nombre de una tabla en una opcion html,.

Comment: La segunda consulta es para acceder a los nombres de las diferentes tablas de mi base de datos. El usuario puede crear varias por lo que tengo que leer las que hay creadas y mostrarlas en el select como opción. Estoy trabajando con un SQL server por lo que no me valen las instrucciones mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Muchisimas gracias a todos por las respuestas! Me habéis dado ideas para solucionarlo. Publico la respuesta por si a alguien le ayuda o si se os ocurre una manera más sencilla.

Cada celda se llamará ("nombre de columna"_"nº de fila"). He almacenado las opciones del select en un array y he medido su longitud. Y dentro de cada select hago un FOR recorriendo ese array y mostrando sus valores.

```
<tbody>            
        <?php
        //query de datos de la celda  
        $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [FIFO] ORDER BY Orden");  
        //query de opciones del select (recetas)
        $results2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME!='FIFO' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME");  
        
        
        //obtengo el numero de recetas
        $aux = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME!='FIFO'");            
        $aux2=sqlsrv_fetch_array($aux);
        $numero_recetas= $aux2[0];
        
        
        //transformo a un array fila las recetas (opciones del select)
        while ($row_recetas = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($results2)){
        $fila_recetas[]= $row_recetas['TABLE_NAME'];                
        } 
        
        
        //ahora formo la tabla
        while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){           
        
        if (isset($_GET['editar'])){  ?>  //opcion tabla editable
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['Orden'];?>
                </td>
                <td>                    
                    <select name="cuba1_<?php echo $row['Orden']?>">
                        <?php for($i = 0; $i < ($numero_recetas); $i++) {; ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?>"><?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?></option> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="cuba2_<?php echo $row['Orden']?>">
                        <?php for($i = 0; $i < ($numero_recetas); $i++) {; ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?>"><?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?></option> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="cuba3_<?php echo $row['Orden']?>">
                        <?php for($i = 0; $i < ($numero_recetas); $i++) {; ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?>"><?php echo $fila_recetas[$i] ?></option> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>          
                   
                   (etc...)

            </tr>          
        <?php } 
        else{ ?>      //opcion tabla no editable (datos guardados)
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Orden']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba1']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba2']?></td>               
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba3']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba4']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba5']?></td>               
                <td><?php echo $row['Cuba6']?></td>
            </tr>
            
        <?php }}   ?>
      </tbody>
```

Voy a adjuntar también una imagen de mi base de datos para dar un poco contexto de lo que quería hacer jajaja

[image: resultado final]
[image: base de datos SQL]